# The books about creating of the own GUI libraries

Tags: wpf, winforms, qt, opengl, graphics

I often create GUI for my own programs through the WinForms, WPF, and Qt, but for me is interesting to understand *how to create the similar platforms*. I want to understand the principles, to look at simple code samples (C, C++, C# or Common Lisp).

How the platforms, similar Qt interact with an operating system for creation of graphic interfaces?

I try to find the books or sites about this info, but I find nothing. Anybody can help me with the links?

It is interesting to me how to create the library which isn't a wrapper over the already existing library. Such library (which is not a wrapper) shall interact somehow with an operating system, receiving and sending the different signals (clicking by a mouse, clicking of keyboard keys, relocation of a mouse, clicking of the hot keys, etc.). I want to understand how to solve these problems myself, without the wrappers using.

P.S. pay attention: I don't ask how to use WinForms, WPF, or Qt (it is other).

Comment: So you wanna find books about how they made Qt, etc?

Comment: Creating of Qt can be considered as a sample... I want to understand the principles of  such libraries creating.

Comment: Did you consider Google? Also before you post further questions you should read the [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) since your question does not live up to the requirements.

Comment: Certainly I looked for. If you have a concrete response for my question, then I will be glad. If the response isn't present, there is no sense to write.

Comment: And than it doesn't conform to requirements?

Comment: stack overflow is  site for problems with code, not for tools/books recommendations. however i dont think this question deserves the downvotes.

Comment: @AntonD: I agree, so I +1'd. :) Bush: have you checked the lately released qt 5 qml book?

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I didn't ask about how to work with Qt. I asked about how platforms, similar Qt interact with an operating system for creation of graphic interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such "platforms" (really: application development frameworks) are created, like most other software, incrementally. You start small and grow, often breaking things as you go along. That's true of all software, of course :)

More seriously though, there is no "how". The "how" is everything that's needed to be a good software developer and encompasses the widely considered software engineering practice. Those are indeed **application development** frameworks. The word "GUI" is conspicuously *absent*. The user interface is but an aspect of such frameworks. E.g. Qt is used in some credit card processing server code. No GUI.

You don't find "books" or "sites" about this, because you are too specific. You want "books" or "sites" about software engineering practice: how to be a good software engineer. There's plenty of those, addressing various aspects of software engineering: **design of interfaces (APIs), reliability, testing, user experience and usability, various aspects of performance, modern GPU programming, the interfaces exposed by the OS of your choice (say [WINAPI](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/index.html)), etc.** Those are the topics of the books you're looking for.

If you want specific anecdotes from development of various frameworks, there's plenty of those around - just google. You may also look at the source code to see how it's done. But there really aren't books about, say, internal architecture of Qt. They'd be next to useless.

Not wanting a wrapper is a bit of a fool's errand, since you don't specify exactly at what level you want to stop. Recall that these days a lot of the "wrappers" are supplied as part of the operating system (WINAPI, glibc/POSIX layer, .Net, WPF, Cocoa).

If you want something that's truly not running against a wrapper, you need to be writing microcode for the CPU. Above it there are only multiple layers of wrappers. The CPU really runs its microcode, that then interprets the higher-level instruction set, that the kernel's machine code is expressed in, that is invoked by multiple layers of user land code. Nominally nobody is programming to the kernel (those would be kernel calls on the NT platform, syscalls on Unices), as you imply you'd like to. You are already using a wrapper: the widely taken WINAPI is a rather big wrapper around the kernel interfaces, just as C and POSIX/UNIX libraries are. If you look at [WINE](http://www.winehq.org) codebase, most of it is implementing WINAPI functionality, not NTDLL (the kernel interface).

If you want to code to the NT kernel interface on Windows, you'll need [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx), but nobody really uses that in developing a high-level framework as it'd be pointless. So wrappers are there to stay.

Now that one recognizes that the wrappers are with us for a reason, the obvious question is: why do you arbitrarily choose a particular layer of wrappers as your stopping point. What's so much better about coding to WINAPI than coding to, say, Qt, or Carbon...

Comment: I want to read about the specified subject for the well understanding how it works "behind the screen". It is interesting to me. It not crime. It is interesting to me how to create the library which isn't a wrapper over the already existing library. Such library (which is not a wrapper) shall interact somehow with an operating system, receiving and sending the different signals (clicking by a mouse, clicking of keyboard keys, relocation of a mouse, clicking of the hot keys, etc.). I want to understand how to solve these problems myself, without the wrappers using.

Comment: I am in full agreement with Bush here. This answer does not attempt to reply to the question.

Comment: To Clemens, b__, datenwolf, genpfault, Florent: this topic is interesting for me. If you don't understand about what I asked, it is not reason for this topic closing.

Comment: @Bush: I did attempt to answer the question. What you want to do is not specific at all. General software engineering practice applies to it. There is nothing more specific just because you're engineering an application framework. A lot of software engineering is about frameworks that are designed for less general use, but that's essentially what it all reduces to.

Comment: @Bush: So I've told you precisely what you need to read about. Read software engineering books that delve into, and I quote myself *design of interfaces (APIs), reliability, testing, user experience and usability, various aspects of performance, modern GPU programming*. There's too many to list, but that's what you want to be reading.

Comment: +1 It's sad that some incompetents downvoted this excellent answer out of their own ignorance. The one point I would offer is that sometimes people write books or articles called something like "The implementation of Qt". But finding such things is what a search engine is for, not SO.

Comment: @Kuba Ober Thank you, I marked it as an answer and will try to use your advice.